# How to decode a base64 encoded string returned from an api correctly

Tags: javascript, python, string, base64, decode

Having a base64 string encoded JSON like object coming from a python API, what is the correct way to decode and parse the encoded JSON in javascript?

Python makes it a byte string literal by adding `b` prefix and additional apostrophes.

I have written the following function using `Buffer.from` and `buf.toString` methods, which is working fine, but the problem is, the string I receive from the API has `b'<encoded-string>'` format. With the initial `b` and the apostrophes(`'`).

```js
const decodedObject: {
  foo?: string;
} = JSON.parse(
  Buffer.from(encodedString.replace("b'", '').replace("'", ''), 'base64').toString(),
);
```

*`atob` and `btoa` seems deprecated I as understand from the warning in my IDE. That's why I used Buffer methods*

So, my question is: Removing those apostrophes and `b` manually didn't feel right. Is there something I might be missing?

For example creating the encoded base64 in python:

```py
>>> import base64
>>> "https://example.com?encoded={}".format(base64.b64encode(str({"foo":"bar"}).encode('utf-8')))
"https://example.com?encoded=b'eydmb28nOiAnYmFyJ30='"
```

In order to decode that base64 in javascript, I need to first remove those prefix and apostrophes.

```js
> console.log(atob('eydmb28nOiAnYmFyJ30='))
{'foo': 'bar'}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the actual kinda of response you get in your post?

Comment: Sure, for example I have this {"foo": "bar"} encoded to base64 (which results in `eyJmb28iOiAiYmFyIn0=`) in a python API. The problem I have is, I receive this string like: `b'eyJmb28iOiAiYmFyIn0='`. I need to remove those additional b' and ' in the API response which breaks the base64 format.

Comment: No really, [in your post, please](/help/how-to-ask), it's a missing detail that should be part of the problem description for everyone to see without needing to read a comment thread =) Also, please mention whether is your own Python server, e.g. whether you control its output, because it's clearly not sending JSON, to which the first question should be "why not? Why is it not `json.dumps`ing its response and serving the response with an `application/json` content type?"

Comment: You want the part of the string between the second and next-to-last characters, so you could use `encodedString.slice(2, encodedString.length - 1)`.

Comment: Try `base64.b64encode(str({"foo":"bar"}).encode()).decode()`

Comment: You don't want a string representation of the `dict`; you want a *JSON* value to pass to another program. `json.dumps` will return a `str` value that you then *encode* in order to base64-code the resulting bytes string. But since JSON values Unicode strings, it's not clear why you need to use base64 encoding at all: how is the value being transferred from your Python code to your JS code?

Comment: why dont you split your string on the single quote `'` like this `yourString.split("'")` . The response will be array with 3 values and your would be on index 1

Comment: A byte string literal uses the `b'...'` syntax, but you don't have a literal; you have a `bytes` value generated by `b64encode`. *Python* will display that using `b'...'`, but they aren't in the value itself. They shouldn't be transferred to the JS code in the first place.

Comment: If the API is providing a string of the form `b'...'`, that API is broken and needs to be fixed.

Comment: The problem is value is inserted with `b'...'` in python and I am trying to handle it in the javascript. An URL is generated and I'm parsing that value from URL query, I am updating the question with more example

Comment: The Python API should be doing something like `b64encode(json.dumps(dict(foo="bar')).encode())`.

Comment: having `base64.b64encode(str({"foo":"bar"}).encode()).decode()` as @JosefZ mentioned fixes the issue with inserting value as `b'...'` in python. But I'm looking for an elegant way of parsing that `b'...'` in javascript. If not I will try to let people make that change in the python API.

Comment: You should file that as a bug *first*, because it is not at all reasonable to expect any client (Python or not) to deal with that kind of Python-specific string format. Do what you need to to work around it in the mean time until they fix the API. (You should not spend your time looking for an more-elegant hack to fix their error.)

Comment: @BerkinAnık fix that Python, because that's not how we generate JSON in Python. See answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that your Python code is pretending strings are JSON, instead of actually using the `json` library to generate proper JSON.

So, let's fix that:

```py
import base64
import json

data = { "foo": "bar" }
encoded_value = base64.b64encode(json.dumps(data))
url = f"https://example.com?encoded={encoded_value}"
```

And done, the `encoded` URL query argument is now a normal, trivially decoded value on the JS side, because we're *guaranteed* that it's proper JSON, just base64 encoded.

Which means that in order to unpack that on the JS side, we just run through the obvious steps:

1. get the query value,
2. decode it,
3. parse it as JSON

So:

```js
// I have no idea if you're running Node, a browser, Deno, etc.
// so substitute window.location or your framework's path object.
const url = new URL(request.path)

// get the encoded value
const query = new URLSearchParams(url.search)
const encoded = query.get(`encoded`)

// turn it back into a JSON string and parse that
const decoded = base64Decode(encoded); // again, no idea where you're running this.
try {
  const unpacked = JSON.parse(decoded);
  console.log(unpacked); // { foo: "bar" }
} catch (e) {
  // ALWAYS run JSON.parse in a try/catch because it can, and will, throw.
}
```

Noting that that `base64Decode(encoded)` is a stand-in for whatever base64 library you're using.